# Javascript - sum of scores in an array

Tags: javascript, function

Im relatively new to javascript and trying to sum all the scores in the following array:

```
[
  { tile: "N", score: 1 },
  { tile: "K", score: 5 },
  { tile: "Z", score: 10 },
  { tile: "X", score: 8 },
  { tile: "D", score: 2 },
  { tile: "A", score: 1 },
  { tile: "E", score: 1 }
]
```

I have tried using this function:

```
function maximumScore(tileHand) {
        return tileHand.reduce((p,c) => p.score + c.score, 0);
    }
```

but the result I get is `NaN` instead of 28. However, when I replace `p.score` in my function with `p`, I get the expected result of 28.

Why is this the case?

Comment: `tileHand.reduce((p, c) => p + c.score, 0);` `p` in your case initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is that the callback for the [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method you use takes up to 4 arguments, and the first one is an *accumulator*. It means that it holds the accumulated value of all of the previous results returned by the callback. In this case, it's a number, not an object. So in each iteration, you have the current sum under `p` argument, not an object.

From the docs:

> **`accumulator`**
>
> > The accumulator accumulates callback's return values. It is the accumulated value previously returned in the last invocation of
> > the callback—or `initialValue`, if it was supplied (see below).

Answer (score 2):

reduce's first argument is the accumulator. So the values are added to it. So it is basically a variable.

```
function maximumScore(tileHand) {
    return tileHand.reduce((p,c) => p + c.score, 0);
}
```

That will keep adding score to p, which starts at 0

Also see [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

```
// get sum of score prop across all objects in array i.e. tileHand
var scoreTotal = tileHand.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  return prev + cur. score;
}, 0);

console.log('Total Score:', scoreTotal);
```

refrence: https://gist.github.com/benwells/0111163b3cccfad0804d994c70de7aa1

Answer (score 0):

p stands for previous (or accumulator/sum) and c for current. You are adding previous score with current score. You then tell the reduce function to start with 0

So it tries to sum 0.score + c.score which will give NaN.

Just do p + c.score

So the loop will be

0 + 1 = 1

1 + 5 = 6

6 + 10 = 16

Etc